# real analysis converging series

Tags: real-analysis

Consider $\{b_{n}\}$ defined recursively by $b_{1}=1$, $b_{2}=1$, $b_{n}=b_{n-2}+b_{n-1}$ for $n>2$. Using the recursive formula prove 
1)$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_{n}}$ exists.
2)Compute the limit as well.
3)Show $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{b_{n}}$ converges.
To prove the first part it is possible to use the identity $b_{n+1}b_{n-1}-b_{n}^{2}=(-1)^{n}$ I proved it using induction but I'm not sure how to use it to prove it let a lone find the limit.

Comment: $$\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} = \frac{b_n + b_{n-1}}{b_n} = 1 + \left(\frac{b_n}{b_{n-1}}\right)^{-1}$$

Comment: It's the Fibonacci sequence. And the limit is the golden ratio.

Answer (score 1):

You said you proved by induction that $b_{n+1}b_{n-1}-b_n^2=(-1)^n$. Then use that to prove $1$. Knowing the limit, call it $\varphi$, exists use the recursive formula to find a quadratic equation satisfied by $\varphi$. For $3$ you can you show $b_n$ grows exponentially. For example, show that $b_n\geqslant C r^n$ for some $r>1$.

Comment: I'm not very good with recursive formulas what do you mean a quadratic equation satisfied by $\phi$